# How do you update SOA values using PowerShell

Tags: domain-name-system, powershell, windows-server-2012

The Windows PowerShell module DnsServer allows managing a Windows DNS Server.

Is it possible to update the SOA record fields such as TTL, Refresh, Expires, etc using the DnsServer module?

To date I've only found a way via WMI to update SOA fields.

Answer (score 1):

TTL and other cache settings can be updated using the [`Set-DNSServerCache`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dnsserver/set-dnsservercache?view=win10-ps) cmdlet. Refresh can be configured using [`Set-DNSServerScavenging`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dnsserver/set-dnsserverscavenging?view=win10-ps). If you are looking to update other fields, a handy exhaustive list of DNS Powershell cmdlets and how to use them can be [found here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dnsserver/?view=win10-ps).